# React Container and Presentable Components with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm reading about container and presentable components. What i understand from concept is

eg:

we have some container component A and inside presentable component B 
we need to embed component B inside component A and from component A shared data with props to component B.

here is how i understood concept basically:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux"
import {testAction} from "store/actions/testAction"
import ComponentB from "Components/b"
import "styles/layout.scss"
class ComponentA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ComponentB data={this.props.testData}/>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  testData: state.testData
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    testAction: bindActionCreators(testAction, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ComponentA);
```

and we need to all events eg: onClick events fetch methods etc. Need to use in ComponentA so in container component right?

but i don't understand something.

eg. I have some **onClick** event in **ComponentB** how i can pass this event from **componentA** ?

eg It's my ComponentB: and there is some onClick event how not keep it in componentB ? and manage it from ComponentA?

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux"
class ComponentB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <p onClick={this.clickMe}>Click me!</p>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  testData: state.testData
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    testAction: bindActionCreators(testAction, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ComponentB);
```

Comment: You can store you "onClick" event in componentA "testAction". And use this in componentB as this.props.testAction.onClick().

Comment: mm. I'm getting this error :/  this.props.testAction.onClick is not a function

Comment: sorry some syntax error. All worked thanks